# Using high resolution thumbnail on iOS

Tags: ios, youtube-api, mobile-safari, youtube-iframe-api

How can I default to the high-res version of my thumbnail in iOS?

This question never had an answer: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/77Vky3bso54

For example, instead of: http://img.youtube.com/vi/XLDDP9f4a-g/hqdefault.jpg I want the player to use: http://img.youtube.com/vi/XLDDP9f4a-g/maxresdefault.jpg

My player is 920px by 518px. I get the high-res thumbnail on my desktop browser, but not on my iPad with iOS 8.4.

I'm using youtube's iframe api to display the player, initialized like this:

```
        new YT.Player(container, {
            videoId: videoId,
            width: 920,
            height: 518,
            playerVars: {
                'autoplay': 0,
                'controls': 1,
                'modestbranding': 1,
                'rel': 0,
                'showinfo': 0
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can try using YoutTube Player demo https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Comment: @Verma can you be more specific? I don't understand.. show me an example.